# NGXS Logger is not accepting custom logger which is a singleton service

Tags: ngxs

I have a custom logger that is a singleton service provided in root and that has a log method. Whenever I try to configure `NgxsLoggerPluginModule.forRoot({ logger: LogService })`. This however always throws an error

```
`
TypeError: this.logger.log is not a function
    at LogWriter.log (ngxs-logger-plugin.js:218)
    at LogWriter.logGrey (ngxs-logger-plugin.js:185)
    at ActionLogger.dispatched (ngxs-logger-plugin.js:69)
    at NgxsLoggerPlugin.handle (ngxs-logger-plugin.js:315)
    at ngxs-store.js:1495
    at InternalDispatcher.dispatchSingle (ngxs-store.js:1722)
    at InternalDispatcher.dispatchByEvents (ngxs-store.js:1681)
    at ngxs-store.js:1647
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:123)
`
```

I've debug the issue and narrowed it down to these lines of code in NgxsLogger source code:

```
`
constructor(options) {
        this.options = options;
        this.options = this.options || (/** @type {?} */ ({}));
        this.logger = options.logger || console; <= here options.logger is just a class expression, its not an instance. 
    }
`
```

The `NgxsLoggerPluginModule.forRoot()` options object, accepts custom logger but it never attempts to instantiate it. How would I instantiate custom logger instance?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to instantiate the Logger prior to providing it to the logger options:

```
export const logger = new LogService(new LogPublishersService());


// ngxs logging
        NgxsLoggerPluginModule.forRoot({
            logger: logger,
            collapsed: false,
            disabled: environment.production
        }),
```

this is not very desirable, so I will not be using NgxsLoggerPlugin. It doesn't seem like there is an Injection token for the logger that you can provide your own instance of a logging service that works nicely with the DI.